# Is tableView.reloadData always necessary?

Tags: ios, uitableview

If I had a UITableView displaying custom cells with some animatable content. I find reloadData causes some flickering in this process and isn't very smooth. Is it acceptable to just grab the visible cells, figure out what ones I need to modify and grab the subviews to animiate the content directly?

Comment: Yes it's ok to do what you are saying about. Just keep in mind, if the cell you are animating is reused, unfinished animation continues on the reused same cell.

Comment: Take a look at "row insertion/deletion/reloading" in UITableView interface. You don't have to reload the whole tableview

Comment: Yes thats true, good to bare that in mind. I suppose the flickering comes from the rebuilding of an entire cells view whereas animating already displaying content doesnt have to do this